# Disabled conditions in Jsp not working as expected?

Tags: java, html, jsp

I have to disable one input text field based on some condtions. Below is the code.

```
<h:inputText maxlength="14" id="adjusAuthAmt" 
    value="#{Budget.fundCodeVO.adjustedAuthorizedAmount}"
    disabled="#{!Budget.enableBudgetAmt || Budget.controlRequired || Budget.fundCodeVoidProtect}"                               
    onchange="javascript:isFormChanged()" onblur="this.value=validateAmountCurrency(this.value,this.id,11);javascript:selectOne=true;javascript:fileSavedFlag=false;" 
/>
```

Here, Budget.enableBudgetAmt is false now. But it still showing in editable mode.

Requirement is If the boolean variable enableBudgetAmt is false then i have to disable this input field.

Please tell me what is the simple thing that i missed here...

Thanks in Advance...

Comment: try ```not Budget.enableBudgetAmt```

Comment: @Karthi: The same condition !Budget.enableBudgetAmt is working fine for some other fields... But there i am checking only one condition... here am checking 3 conditions... do we need to put any parathensis???

Comment: are you sure Budget.controlRequired and Budget.fundCodeVoidProtect are both false?

Comment: Yes, The other Two conditions are FALSE